# Kubernetes storage class for blob storage (AZURE storage account)

Tags: kubernetes, aks

Can we use azure storage account: blob for storing EFK logs using persistent volume.
Ihv verified below article i didn't see anything related to blob
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-storage
please let me know if we can use blob for k8s storage clz

Answer (score 0):

Not directly [Azure blob storage](https://www.msp360.com/resources/blog/microsoft-azure-storage-types-explained/) is accessible via API's rather than directly attached to a VM.

The K8s CSI (Container Storage Interface) is primarily there for disk or network attached storage. Aka something pretending to be a HDD/SSD or a network share, not something pretending to be a web page.

[While you might be able to find something that uses a little of the VM's disk space as a buffer as it proxies to the blob storage (in Linux there are FUSE drivers which can do this) the IO is through the floor.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-how-to-mount-container-linux)

If you're talking logs you're MUCH better off with something that understands the blob storage and ships the logs from the cluster to blob storage.